# Why do I get error code 401 when sending post request

Tags: javascript, cookies, request, http-headers, http-post

From the following request I get status code 302 redirect. But I want to send cookies I've received from the response with the redirect to the next page. Right now I get status code 401 when sending the request, and I've figured out that it's because I need to send the cookies along with the redirect, but I don't get the cookies until I fetch the url that gives me the redirect. How do I do that?

```
async function login (url) {
        let request = await fetch(url, {
            method: 'POST',
            credentials: 'include',
            headers: { 'Content-Type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' },
            body: 'username=name&password=pass&submit=login',
        })

        return request

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In general body data type must match the Content-Type header. so in your case you have to use

```
body: new URLSearchParams({
     'userName': 'name',
      'password': 'pass',
      'grant_type': 'password'
    }),
```

Comment: I tried that, and then I got status code 403 'forbidden' instead.